# Post array of strings to web API method

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, post, asp.net-web-api

**this is my client side ajax call:**

```
    var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];

    var jsonText = { data: list };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/scheduledItemPriceStatus/updateStatusToDelete",
        data: jsonText,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function() { alert("it worked!"); },
        failure: function() { alert("not working..."); }
    });
```

**this is chrome network header:**

```
Request URL:http://localhost:2538/api/scheduledItemPriceStatus/updateStatusToDelete

Request Method:POST

Request Headersview source

Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

Accept-Charset:ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8

Connection:keep-alive

Content-Length:27

Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8

Host:localhost:2538

Origin:http://localhost:2538

Referer:http://localhost:2538/Pricing/ScheduledItemPrices

User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11

X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
```

Form Dataview URL encoded

```
data:a
data:b
data:c
data:d
```

**this is my webapi controller method:**

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateStatusToDelete(string[] data)
```

**result:**

when I debug, the data parameter in UpdateStatusToDelete returns `{string[0]}` instead of data:a
data:b
data:c
data:d

What am I doing wrong? Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Hmmm, I think you should directly pass the `list` variable as the data field in your ajax call. Right now, it looks like you are passing an object which has an array of strings as a member field called "data".

Comment: does that first line compile..? var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]? it should be like this `string[] list = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};`

Comment: @Eunyoung Ro look at my comment do you have a typo..? also are you sure that code compiles..?

Answer (score 34):

For passing simply types, the data to post must take the form of a name value pair with the name portion being an empty string. So you need to make the Ajax call like so:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/api/values",
  data: { "": list },
  dataType: "json",
  success: function() { alert("it worked!"); },
  failure: function() { alert("not working..."); }
});
```

Additionally, on your Web API action, annotate it w/ the [FromBody] attribute. Something like:

```
public void Post([FromBody]string[] values)
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: I still get a null values for values using this approach. the one different is My API also has Non body parameters.
Something like 

public void Post( string id, [FromBody]string[] values)

Answer (score 4):

You should pass the `list` itself, and not any other object wrapping it.

E.g. pass the following:

```
var list = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
```

in

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/scheduledItemPriceStatus/updateStatusToDelete",
        // Pass the list itself
        data: list, 
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function() { alert("it worked!"); },
        failure: function() { alert("not working..."); }
    });
```

Your method signature on server is correct.

Answer (score 2):

use `var jsonText = { data: JSON.stringify(list)}`

Comment: Chris there is now from what I can tell that the list portion will compile.. check the code out and tell me.... [] should be { }

Answer (score 1):

In the backend, you could use `FormDataCollection.GetValues(string key)` to return an array of strings for that parameter.

```
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateStatusToDelete(FormDataCollection formData) {
    string[] data = formData.GetValues("data");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use the method above to send array as suggested by cris in your jquery ajax call.
JSON data is usually in key value pair.

```
  var tmp = [];
  tmp.push({
  //this is the key name 'a'  "a": "your value", //it could be anything here in 
   //string format.
    "b": "b",
    "c": "c",
    "d": "d"
   });

 { data: JSON.stringify(tmp);}
```

You can also accomplish above by using two dimensional array

Additionally do this in the webapi project.

under the models folder in your web api project create a class file. Possibly **class1.cs**.

Create 4 properties

```
public string a {get; set;}
public string b {get; set;}
public string c {get; set;}
public string d {get; set;}
```

Now do this in your controller

```
using projectname.models

[HttpPost]
public return-type actionname(List<Class1> obj)
{
  //Further logic goes here
}
```

I am sure this will work.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the dataType won't help you.

This is how I do it  :

```
var SizeSequence = {};
SizeSequence.Id = parseInt(document.querySelector("dd#Sequence_Id").textContent);
SizeSequence.IncludedSizes = [];
var sizes = document.querySelectorAll("table#IncludedElements td#Size_Name");
// skipping the first row (template)
for (var i = 1, l = sizes.length ; i != sizes.length ; SizeSequence.IncludedSizes.push(sizes[i++].textContent));

$.ajax("/api/SizeSequence/" + SizeSequence.Id, { 
     method: "POST",
     contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
     data: JSON.stringify(SizeSequence.IncludedSizes), 
...
```

The Server Part

```
// /api/SizeSequence/5
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostSaveSizeSequence(int? Id, List<String> IncludedSizes)
    {
        if (Id == null || IncludedSizes == null || IncludedSizes.Exists( s => String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)))
            return BadRequest();
        try
        {

            await this.Repo.SaveSizeSequenceAsync(Id.Value, IncludedSizes );
            return Ok();
        }
        catch ( Exception exc)
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
    }
```

### References

[jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with `JSON.stringify`, which feels more semantically intuitive than putting things in an object with an empty string key. (I am using Web API 2, not sure if that matters.)

### Client code

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST', //also works for PUT or DELETE
    url: '/api/UserRole',
    contentType: "application/json",
    data: JSON.stringify(["name1", "name2"])
})
```

### Server Code

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/UserRole")]
public IHttpActionResult AddUsers(string[] usernames)
```