# Javascript send an input as array to a C# WebAPI

Tags: javascript, c#, forms, post

-------------------------EDIT--------------------------------

It's not a duplicate because I can't use an ajax Request, as asked on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14208888/post-array-of-strings-to-web-api-method) question.

---

I'm creating a form in javascript to call a c# WebApi that will return a xls file (that's why I'm creating a form and not an ajax call).
The webApi must receive an array of integer, that will correspond to a list of ids of objects.
The webApi is the following

```
[Route("getExcel")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage getExcel([FromBody]int[] ids)
{
...
}
```

the form I'm building is like this:

```
var form = document.createElement("form");
form.setAttribute('method', "post");
setAttribute('action', baseUrl + "api/processos/getExcel");
form.setAttribute('target', "_blank");
var rows = $("#tbl").dataTable().fnGetNodes();
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++)
{
  ids = $("#tbl").dataTable().fnGetData(i).processosId; 
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute('type', "text");
  input.setAttribute('name', "ids[]");
  input.setAttribute('value', ids);
  form.appendChild(input);
}
document.body.appendChild(form);
form.submit();
```

The `ids` on the WebApi is empty (but not null)... When watching on Fiddler, the Raw View shows this `ids=15&ids=14&ids=13&ids=12&ids=11` which is exactly what I need...
Why isn't associating with the WebApi ids ?  If I send that exact values in the URL (and changing the `[FromBody]` to `[FromUri]` it works...

-------------------EDIT------------------------------

this is what is in the array `ids` on the WebApi when the method is called:
`ids {int[0]}` (as seen while debugging)

Comment: Can you try changing `name` to be `id[]`?

Comment: it's not a duplicate because I can't use an ajax Request, it must be with a form...

Comment: changing the name doesn't affect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the solution is to create a model on the backend such this:

```
public class ExcelIds
{
    public int[] ids { get; set; }
}
```

and change the controller to:

```
[Route("getExcel")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage getExcel([FromBody]ExcelIds model)
{
    //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `FormDataCollection.GetValues(string Key)` to get an array of strings, that you could later convert to int[].

```
[Route("getExcel")]
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage getExcel(FormDataCollection data)
{
   string[] ids = data.GetValues("ids");
   ...
}
```